# Error: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views camera

Tags: java, android, eclipse, tablet

This project should see points in someone's face and start to play video. I divided screen into three area and named. When I run project camera suddenly see 2nd area and there is no error because there is no action in 2nd area. But when camera see 1st or 3rd area -project should start to play video in these areas- project suddenly closed.

***This is my logcat errors:***

```
08-28 11:08:09.392: E/AndroidRuntime(4635): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-373
08-28 11:08:09.392: E/AndroidRuntime(4635): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
08-28 11:08:09.392: E/AndroidRuntime(4635):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4078)
08-28 11:08:09.392: E/AndroidRuntime(4635):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:714)
08-28 11:08:09.392: E/AndroidRuntime(4635):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12678)
08-28 11:08:09.392: E/AndroidRuntime(4635):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12678)
08-28 11:08:09.392: E/AndroidRuntime(4635):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12678)
08-28 11:08:09.392: E/AndroidRuntime(4635):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12678)
08-28 11:08:09.392: E/AndroidRuntime(4635):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:268)
08-28 11:08:09.392: E/AndroidRuntime(4635):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12678)
08-28 11:08:09.392: E/AndroidRuntime(4635):     at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:213)
08-28 11:08:09.392: E/AndroidRuntime(4635):     at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:202)
08-28 11:08:09.392: E/AndroidRuntime(4635):     at org.opencv.samples.facedetect.FdActivity.startPlaying(FdActivity.java:526)
08-28 11:08:09.392: E/AndroidRuntime(4635):     at org.opencv.samples.facedetect.FdActivity.onCameraFrame(FdActivity.java:372)
08-28 11:08:09.392: E/AndroidRuntime(4635):     at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.deliverAndDrawFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:387)
08-28 11:08:09.392: E/AndroidRuntime(4635):     at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$CameraWorker.run(JavaCameraView.java:321)
08-28 11:08:09.392: E/AndroidRuntime(4635):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

***Here is necessary part of main code.***

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    setContentView(R.layout.face_detect_surface_view);

    .....

    mMethodSeekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.methodSeekBar);
    mValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.method);

    .....
    videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);

    // Creating MediaController
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

    videoView.setVideoURI(uri2);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();


    currentPosition = 0;


}

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
.....
    }
        @Override
        public void onResume() {
    ....
        }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
...
    }

@Override 
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        mGray = inputFrame.gray();

        if (mAbsoluteFaceSize == 0) {
            int height = mGray.rows();
            if (Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize) > 0) {
                mAbsoluteFaceSize = Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize);
            }
        }

        if (mZoomWindow == null || mZoomWindow2 == null)
            CreateAuxiliaryMats();

        MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();

            if (mJavaDetector != null)
                mJavaDetector.detectMultiScale(mGray, faces, 1.1, 2,
                        2, // TODO: objdetect.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
                        new Size(mAbsoluteFaceSize, mAbsoluteFaceSize),
                        new Size());

        Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++) {
            //Core.rectangle(mRgba, facesArray[i].tl(), facesArray[i].br(),
                //  FACE_RECT_COLOR, 3);
            xCenter = (facesArray[i].x + facesArray[i].width + facesArray[i].x) / 2;
            yCenter = (facesArray[i].y + facesArray[i].y + facesArray[i].height) / 2;
            Point center = new Point(xCenter, yCenter);

            //Core.circle(mRgba, center, 10, new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 3);

            Log.i("Point Location", Double.toString(xCenter));


            if(xCenter>50 && xCenter<250 ){
                Log.i("Point Location","Area 1");
                startPlaying(false);
                }
            else if (xCenter>250 && xCenter<450) {
                Log.i("Point Location","Area 2");
                /*
                videoView.stopPlayback();
                videoView.setVideoURI(uri2);
                videoView.requestFocus();
                videoView.start();
                */
            }
            else if (xCenter>450 && xCenter <650){
                Log.i("Point Location","Area 3");
                startPlaying(false);
            }

            /*Core.putText(mRgba, "[" + center.x + "," + center.y + "]",
                    new Point(center.x + 20, center.y + 20),
                    Core.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, new Scalar(255, 255, 255,
                            255));     

                              //KOORDINATLARI YAZAN FONKSIYON//   */



            Rect r = facesArray[i];
            // compute the eye area
            Rect eyearea = new Rect(r.x + r.width / 8,
                    (int) (r.y + (r.height / 4.5)), r.width - 2 * r.width / 8,
                    (int) (r.height / 3.0));
            // split it
            Rect eyearea_right = new Rect(r.x + r.width / 16,
                    (int) (r.y + (r.height / 4.5)),
                    (r.width - 2 * r.width / 16) / 2, (int) (r.height / 3.0));
            Rect eyearea_left = new Rect(r.x + r.width / 16
                    + (r.width - 2 * r.width / 16) / 2,
                    (int) (r.y + (r.height / 4.5)),
                    (r.width - 2 * r.width / 16) / 2, (int) (r.height / 3.0));
            // draw the area - mGray is working grayscale mat, if you want to
            // see area in rgb preview, change mGray to mRgba
            Core.rectangle(mRgba, eyearea_left.tl(), eyearea_left.br(),
                    new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 2);
            Core.rectangle(mRgba, eyearea_right.tl(), eyearea_right.br(),
                    new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 2);

            if (learn_frames < 5) {
                teplateR = get_template(mJavaDetectorEye, eyearea_right, 24);
                teplateL = get_template(mJavaDetectorEye, eyearea_left, 24);
                learn_frames++;
            } else {
                // Learning finished, use the new templates for template
                // matching
                // match_eye(eyearea_right, teplateR, method); 
                 //match_eye(eyearea_left, teplateL, method); 

            }



        }

        return mRgba;
    }
    .....
}
```

}

***And I think  there is a problem :***

```
  private void startPlaying(boolean startFromCurrent) { //IHTIYAC 1

        videoView.stopPlayback();
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri1);
        //videoView.requestFocus();

...
            }
    });

    }
```

Comment: This error occurs when you try to fire events on views programmatically from a thread different from Main thread (sometimes called UI thread). You should "wrap" such calls with `Runnable` object and send it into the Main thread queue by `runOnUiThread()` method. Line numbers in an exception trace will lead you to piece of your code that causes the error.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou ok but where should I put runOnUiThread() method. Sorry, I'm new in Android

Comment: first look at the line 321 of `JavaCameraView.java` class

Comment: can you post your logcat completely !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you suppose that `startPlaying()` is the origin of the error, execute all methods related to Android views inside the `runOnUiThread()`:

```
private void startPlaying(boolean startFromCurrent) { 
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){  
            videoView.stopPlayback();
            videoView.setVideoURI(uri1);
        }
    });
...
```